# Как массив байт разбить на биты, инвертировать его и собрать обратно в байты?

Tags: битовые-операции, c, c#

Как массив байт разбить на биты, инвертировать его и собрать обратно в байты?

Comment: инвертировать каждый бит или изменить порядок бит на обратный?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Инвертировать можно целый байт, пример с массивом

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[5] {1, 2, 10, 64, 128};
for (int i=0; i<bytes.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = (byte) (~bytes[i]);
}
```

Оператор ~ делает логический NOT только для типов `int, uint, long и ulong`, поэтому надо приводить к типу byte явно. [Источник msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d2bd4x66.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, всё чётко работает!